# What is the difference between sudo -u postgres psql and sudo psql -U postgres?

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql

I'm new to Postgres and Bash so I'm not sure what the difference is.

I'm trying to automate in a bash script updating a table in Postgres. I have the .sql file and I've created `.pgpass` file with 600.

The a script that is provided to me uses `sudo -u postgres psql db -w < .sql` and it fails because it can't find the pass.

Whereas, `sudo psql -U postgres db -w < .sql` doesn't prompt for a pass and is able to update.

So what's the difference? Why can't the first command get the pass from the .pgpass?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo -u postgres` is running the rest of the command string as the UNIX user `postgres`

`sudo psql -U postgres db -w` is running the command as the UNIX user `root` and (presumeably) connecting to postgres as the user "postgres"

Probably the .pgpass file doesn't exist for the unix user postgres.

Comment: Most installations configure `peer` authentication, so the `postgres` user like gets trusted because its unix username matches its postgres username.

Answer (score 0):

It is a case of peer autentication. If you're running user x and you have user x on your database you're trusted by postgres so you don't have to use password (default settings of instalation). Running sudo psql -u x you're trying to connect from user root to database as user x... root!=x so you need password. Client authentication is controlled by a [configuration file pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) You can also provide password [via .pgpass file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-pgpass.html). You'll find all needed informations in PostgreSQL documentation.